# Eclipse Maven Plugin: Duplicate Class Error

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, tomcat, maven-plugin

I'm trying to deploy my project using Maven in Eclipse, but I am getting a lot of duplicate class errors. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>clientservices.tas</groupId>
    <artifactId>tas</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>tas</name>

    <properties>
        <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/tas</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>clientservices</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>d-ClientServices-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://nexus.xxx.net/nexus/content/repositories/d-ClientServices-snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>d-ClientServices-releases</id>
            <url>http://nexus.xxx.net/nexus/content/repositories/d-ClientServices-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.39</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.39</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.39</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-el-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
            <version>3.59.81</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cu</artifactId>
            <version>3.59.81</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cisuz</artifactId>
            <version>3.59.81</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>tas</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_UI_RRNScreenFields.java:[28,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_UI_RRNScreenFields
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_PasUserAccessCodeSetup.java:[17,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasUserAccessCodeSetup
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\tbl\tas\MT_TasListExport.java:[17,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasListExport
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_RRNStatus.java:[22,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNStatus
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_RRNDelete.java:[24,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNDelete
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\tbl\tas\MT_TasBaiCollection.java:[24,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasBaiCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\sgml\MT_SgmlSubstitutions.java:[16,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.sgml.MT_SgmlSubstitutions
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tas\MT_TasEntryServlet.java:[29,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasEntryServlet
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tbl\tas\MT_TasBaiSearchCriteria.java:[23,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasBaiSearchCriteria
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_UI_PasUserFields.java:[14,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UI_PasUserFields
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\sgml\MT_Sgml.java:[22,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.sgml.MT_Sgml
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_UI_RRNLookupFields.java:[30,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_UI_RRNLookupFields
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\presentation\MT_IterValueTagHandler.java:[25,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.presentation.MT_IterValueTagHandler
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tas\MT_TasListExport.java:[17,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasListExport
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pool\MT_ConnectionPool.java:[18,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pool.MT_ConnectionPool
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tas\MT_TasBaiCollection.java:[24,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasBaiCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tas\MT_Tas.java:[26,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_Tas
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_PasServletController.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasServletController
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tas\MT_TasVerifyServlet.java:[25,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasVerifyServlet
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\tbl\tas\MT_TasSearchCriteria.java:[23,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasSearchCriteria
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tbl\tas\MT_TasEntryServlet.java:[30,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasEntryServlet
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pool\MT_UI_PoolControlFields.java:[14,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pool.MT_UI_PoolControlFields
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pool\MT_PooledConnInfo.java:[10,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pool.MT_PooledConnInfo
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_RRNVerifyButtons.java:[28,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNVerifyButtons
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\sgml\MT_SgmlLabel.java:[11,0] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.sgml.MT_SgmlLabel
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tbl\tas\MT_TasCollection.java:[12,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_RRNView.java:[23,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNView
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_PageCollection.java:[17,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_PageCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_ConfLetter.java:[17,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_ConfLetter
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pas\MT_UI_PasUserAuditFields.java:[14,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UI_PasUserAuditFields
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tbl\tas\MT_TasSearchCriteria.java:[23,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasSearchCriteria
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_PasAccessCodeList.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasAccessCodeList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_PasUserAddAccessSetup.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasUserAddAccessSetup
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pas\MT_PasButtons.java:[22,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasButtons
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tbl\tas\MT_Tas.java:[26,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_Tas
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_PasUserAccessAuditList.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasUserAccessAuditList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\tbl\tas\MT_TasVerifyServlet.java:[25,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasVerifyServlet
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_PasUserApplAuditList.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasUserApplAuditList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_UI_RRNScreenFieldsChange.java:[20,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_UI_RRNScreenFieldsChange
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pool\MT_ConnectionReaper.java:[13,0] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pool.MT_ConnectionReaper
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_RRNVEView.java:[23,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNVEView
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_MRVerify.java:[22,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_MRVerify
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_UI_RRNSession.java:[13,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_UI_RRNSession
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tbl\MT_UI_TblScreen.java:[10,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.MT_UI_TblScreen
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\tbl\tas\MT_TasListServlet.java:[28,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasListServlet
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pas\MT_PasApplicationList.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasApplicationList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_UI_ConfLetterFields.java:[30,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_UI_ConfLetterFields
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_RRNButton.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNButton
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_UI_AdviceFields.java:[29,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_UI_AdviceFields
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\sgml\MT_SgmlSubstitutionEntry.java:[10,0] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.sgml.MT_SgmlSubstitutionEntry
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_UserAccessCodeAuditCollection.java:[19,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UserAccessCodeAuditCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_MRCheck.java:[22,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_MRCheck
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\presentation\MT_GetValueTagHandler.java:[25,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.presentation.MT_GetValueTagHandler
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pas\MT_UserCollection.java:[17,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UserCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_MRList.java:[23,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_MRList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\presentation\MT_StringDataCollection.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.presentation.MT_StringDataCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_UI_DropDownBoxes.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_UI_DropDownBoxes
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_PasUserList.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasUserList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_ConfList.java:[23,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_ConfList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pool\MT_PooledConnCollection.java:[19,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pool.MT_PooledConnCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pas\MT_PasUserAccessCodeAuditList.java:[22,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasUserAccessCodeAuditList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pool\MT_PoolControlList.java:[22,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pool.MT_PoolControlList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_RRNServletController.java:[26,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNServletController
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\presentation\MT_AttributeForGetValueTagHandler.java:[18,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.presentation.MT_AttributeForGetValueTagHandler
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tas\MT_TasBaiSearchCriteria.java:[23,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasBaiSearchCriteria
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\sgml\MT_Exception_SgmlLabel.java:[16,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.sgml.MT_Exception_SgmlLabel
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_RRNVerify.java:[26,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNVerify
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_UserAccessCodeAudit.java:[19,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UserAccessCodeAudit
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_RRNServlet.java:[17,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNServlet
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pas\MT_User.java:[17,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_User
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_RRNConfLetter.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNConfLetter
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_RRNVEList.java:[22,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNVEList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pas\MT_UI_PasUserAccessCodeAuditFields.java:[14,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UI_PasUserAccessCodeAuditFields
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_MRVEList.java:[23,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_MRVEList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_UserAccessAuditCollection.java:[19,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UserAccessAuditCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_PasUserSetup.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasUserSetup
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_RRNQuery.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNQuery
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_RRNSetupButtons.java:[22,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNSetupButtons
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\tbl\tas\MT_TasBai.java:[17,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasBai
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_RRNSetup.java:[24,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNSetup
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_RRNDeleteList.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNDeleteList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pas\MT_UserAuditCollection.java:[18,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UserAuditCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_UI_ScreenField.java:[28,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_UI_ScreenField
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tas\MT_TasBai.java:[17,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasBai
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_RRNWIPList.java:[22,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNWIPList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\tbl\MT_TblButtons.java:[24,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.MT_TblButtons
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_UI_PasUserAccessFields.java:[14,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UI_PasUserAccessFields
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pas\MT_UserApplicationCollection.java:[19,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UserApplicationCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pas\MT_UserApplication.java:[17,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UserApplication
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\presentation\MT_BooleanValues.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.presentation.MT_BooleanValues
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_ConfLetterCollection.java:[18,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_ConfLetterCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pas\MT_UserAccessCodeCollection.java:[19,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UserAccessCodeCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_UserAccessCode.java:[17,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UserAccessCode
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_UserApplAuditCollection.java:[19,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UserApplAuditCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pas\MT_UserAccess.java:[19,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UserAccess
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_RRNLookup.java:[23,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNLookup
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_RRNUtility.java:[16,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNUtility
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pas\MT_UserAudit.java:[20,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UserAudit
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pool\MT_PoolControl.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pool.MT_PoolControl
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tas\MT_TasCollection.java:[12,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasCollection
[INFO] 100 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.297s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 23 10:02:05 EDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/130M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project tas: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_UI_RRNScreenFields.java:[28,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_UI_RRNScreenFields
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_PasUserAccessCodeSetup.java:[17,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasUserAccessCodeSetup
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\tbl\tas\MT_TasListExport.java:[17,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasListExport
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_RRNStatus.java:[22,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNStatus
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_RRNDelete.java:[24,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNDelete
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\tbl\tas\MT_TasBaiCollection.java:[24,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasBaiCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\sgml\MT_SgmlSubstitutions.java:[16,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.sgml.MT_SgmlSubstitutions
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tas\MT_TasEntryServlet.java:[29,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasEntryServlet
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tbl\tas\MT_TasBaiSearchCriteria.java:[23,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasBaiSearchCriteria
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_UI_PasUserFields.java:[14,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UI_PasUserFields
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\sgml\MT_Sgml.java:[22,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.sgml.MT_Sgml
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_UI_RRNLookupFields.java:[30,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_UI_RRNLookupFields
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\presentation\MT_IterValueTagHandler.java:[25,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.presentation.MT_IterValueTagHandler
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tas\MT_TasListExport.java:[17,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasListExport
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pool\MT_ConnectionPool.java:[18,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pool.MT_ConnectionPool
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tas\MT_TasBaiCollection.java:[24,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasBaiCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tas\MT_Tas.java:[26,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_Tas
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_PasServletController.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasServletController
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tas\MT_TasVerifyServlet.java:[25,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasVerifyServlet
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\tbl\tas\MT_TasSearchCriteria.java:[23,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasSearchCriteria
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tbl\tas\MT_TasEntryServlet.java:[30,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasEntryServlet
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pool\MT_UI_PoolControlFields.java:[14,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pool.MT_UI_PoolControlFields
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pool\MT_PooledConnInfo.java:[10,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pool.MT_PooledConnInfo
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_RRNVerifyButtons.java:[28,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNVerifyButtons
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\sgml\MT_SgmlLabel.java:[11,0] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.sgml.MT_SgmlLabel
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tbl\tas\MT_TasCollection.java:[12,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_RRNView.java:[23,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNView
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_PageCollection.java:[17,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_PageCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_ConfLetter.java:[17,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_ConfLetter
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pas\MT_UI_PasUserAuditFields.java:[14,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UI_PasUserAuditFields
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tbl\tas\MT_TasSearchCriteria.java:[23,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasSearchCriteria
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_PasAccessCodeList.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasAccessCodeList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_PasUserAddAccessSetup.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasUserAddAccessSetup
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pas\MT_PasButtons.java:[22,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasButtons
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tbl\tas\MT_Tas.java:[26,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_Tas
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_PasUserAccessAuditList.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasUserAccessAuditList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\tbl\tas\MT_TasVerifyServlet.java:[25,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasVerifyServlet
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_PasUserApplAuditList.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasUserApplAuditList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_UI_RRNScreenFieldsChange.java:[20,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_UI_RRNScreenFieldsChange
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pool\MT_ConnectionReaper.java:[13,0] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pool.MT_ConnectionReaper
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_RRNVEView.java:[23,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNVEView
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_MRVerify.java:[22,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_MRVerify
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_UI_RRNSession.java:[13,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_UI_RRNSession
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tbl\MT_UI_TblScreen.java:[10,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.MT_UI_TblScreen
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\tbl\tas\MT_TasListServlet.java:[28,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasListServlet
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pas\MT_PasApplicationList.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasApplicationList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_UI_ConfLetterFields.java:[30,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_UI_ConfLetterFields
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_RRNButton.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNButton
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_UI_AdviceFields.java:[29,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_UI_AdviceFields
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\sgml\MT_SgmlSubstitutionEntry.java:[10,0] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.sgml.MT_SgmlSubstitutionEntry
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_UserAccessCodeAuditCollection.java:[19,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UserAccessCodeAuditCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_MRCheck.java:[22,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_MRCheck
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\presentation\MT_GetValueTagHandler.java:[25,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.presentation.MT_GetValueTagHandler
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pas\MT_UserCollection.java:[17,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_UserCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_MRList.java:[23,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_MRList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\presentation\MT_StringDataCollection.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.presentation.MT_StringDataCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_UI_DropDownBoxes.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_UI_DropDownBoxes
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\pas\MT_PasUserList.java:[21,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasUserList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\rrn\MT_ConfList.java:[23,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_ConfList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pool\MT_PooledConnCollection.java:[19,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pool.MT_PooledConnCollection
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pas\MT_PasUserAccessCodeAuditList.java:[22,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pas.MT_PasUserAccessCodeAuditList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\pool\MT_PoolControlList.java:[22,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.pool.MT_PoolControlList
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\rrn\MT_RRNServletController.java:[26,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.rrn.MT_RRNServletController
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\presentation\MT_AttributeForGetValueTagHandler.java:[18,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.presentation.MT_AttributeForGetValueTagHandler
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\tas\MT_TasBaiSearchCriteria.java:[23,7] error: duplicate class: com.xxx.mt.tbl.tas.MT_TasBaiSearchCriteria
[ERROR] \Users\xbbldzy\TAS2\tas\src\main\java\com\xxx\mt\sgml\MT_Exception_SgmlLabel.java:[16,7]
```

I don't actually see any classes being duplicated in my project. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check that your project is not importing classes in the same packages that are due to be compiled. Sounds like you have something in your project that may be shadowing something already present.

This is usually seen when a source class has the same fully qualified name as something that's already in the classpath i.e. compiled or some jar dependency.

Answer (score 0):

May be the name in artifactId

```
<artifactId>tas</artifactId>
```

is already used earlier and keeping referrence of this name try anything different name.